# How to fix the website view not above 1440px

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My current website is this https://resillience.in
It is completely responsive below 1440px and works fine

[image]

But it looks wierd **when viewed at 2560px** as shown below

[image]

Don't want to change the things also in % to make it responsive at 2560px

How to fix the view at 1440px and have a work around like shown below
If viewed at higher, it adds padding from both sides.

Also adding `max-width:1440px` in the main html css file, I cannot achieve the desired result

[image]

The following code also might not solve

```
#root {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Because some of the images are having its css property as

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
```

Comment: I just corrected it, I meant width only!

Comment: Please do not say overly vague stuff like _“Also max-width:1440px was not working”_ - explain, or even better, show in form of code, where exactly you tried to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,you can apply this CSS to your `#root`  element:

```
#root {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will limit the overall width at 1400px and center it horizontally when the window is wider than 1400px.

I don't know if there are any details in other pages of your website which would cause a problem in conjunction with those settings (I don't see any at first sight), but this would be an easy, general procedure to get what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, but this also will not work, because there are some images whose css property is set to position: absolute; right: 0;

Comment: If that absolute position relates to the window,  add `position: relative` to `#root` to make it the next higher ancestor which has relative position, and the absolute position will be relative to `#root`. As I wrote, there will be other details to fix, but those you'll have to adapt yourself - it would be unrealistic to expect a simple four-line solution, but that's the general way to go.

Answer (score 0):

add `justify-content: flex-end;` to right side menu and I had changed some CSS to look beautiful. Please go through this.

```
.jss6 {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.jss7, .jss18 {
  margin: 0 10px; /* to add space between a tag and dropdown */
}
 
.active {
  border: none;
}

.active::before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3672c0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try do the following:

```
#root {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  #root {
    width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto; // for centering
  }
}
```

setting the width to fixed-size might solve the issue, from my quick review, why? cuz u probably used width: 100% inside the root div, so setting the root div to fixed-size always be related to that 100% = 1440px; :) let me know